# How to do a scroll toolbar off screen keeping the tabs in Vuetifyjs?

Tags: vuetify.js

I want to keep tabs appeared on top when scrolling down.

Vuetify's `v-toolbar` has this prop `scroll-toolbar-off-screen` that says `Will transition the toolbar off screen when scrolling down` but doesn't seem to work.

Has anyone able to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `scroll-threshold` as well which can be a hard-coded height or the id of an element (I had trouble getting the latter to work):

```
<v-toolbar app scroll-off-screen scroll-threshold="65">
  <v-toolbar-title>Title</v-toolbar-title>
  <v-spacer></v-spacer>
  <v-btn icon>
    <v-icon>apps</v-icon>
  </v-btn>
</v-toolbar>
```